# How to use the key of an keyvalue object as propperty name of an other object in angular template

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-template

How to use the key of an keyvalue object as propperty name of an other object in angular template

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">
{{ (stati | async)?.[item.key] }} // doesn't work
</ion-col>
```

item.key is the name of the property I need from "stati"?

Object Examples:

```
items: { 
  item1: {id: 1, title: "xy", ... }, 
  item1: {id: 2, title: "xy", ... }, 
  item1: {id: 2, title: "xy", ... }
}
stati: { 
  'item1': 'xy1', 
  'item2': 'xy2', 
  'item3': 'xy3' 
}
```

What I need:
Only the value of the stati object with the corresponding key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(stati | async)` could return `undefined`, or `null`.
Try to wrap with if condition:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(stati | async) as _stati">
  <ion-col *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">
    {{ _stati[item.key] }}
  </ion-col>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This works, but I don't need all entrys of stati, just one specific, how can I do this without looping all.

Comment: I don't get your idea, can you explain a bit which one you need to printing out?

Comment: @Bolin this answer exactly do what you described. note that he didn't only add `ngIf`, but also changed your code to `_stati[item.key]`. here is working example online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebtlit

Answer (score 0):

Try using object.keys and the index of the key you need

```
let objArr = [
    'apple',
    'microsoft',
    'amazon',
    'alphabet',
    'tencent',
    'alibaba'
];
console.log(Object.keys(objArr))
```

From the key you can fetch the respective value from the object

```
var requiredKey = Object.keys(objArr)[2] //amazon
var obj = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
Object.assign(obj, {key3: requiredKey});
//There are other ways too
```

Hope this answers your question.